# How to pause and resume downloading in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, nsurlconnection

By using default NSURLConnection and its delegate methods we can easily download the files. while downloading if internet connection is not available the downloading process has to be paused & after connection established resume the downloading..

Can any one explain me how can I implement this, and If you have any sample code relating to the pause, resume downloading. If it is in Objective-c, or C is better.

Comment: Are you downloading / connecting via HTTP, FTP or ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

[Resuming interrupted downloads](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#resuming_interrupted_downloads)

> As of v0.94, ASIHTTPRequest can resume partial downloads.

Edit:

[Cancelling an asynchronous request](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#cancelling_an_asychronous_request)

Comment: Thank You, Resuming the download is ok. How to handle the pause while internet disables